# Convert groovy list to Yaml

Tags: groovy, ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

I am looking to convert a list in groovy

```
array = ['hostname1','hostname2','hostname3']
```

into an Ansible inventory Yaml format similar to

```
---
all:
  hosts:
     hostname1:
     hostname2:
     hostname3:
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlBuilder

def config = new YamlBuilder() 

def array = ['hostname1','hostname2','hostname3']

config {
    all {
        hosts(array)
    }
}

println config.toString()
```

To print

```
---
all:
  hosts:
  - "hostname1"
  - "hostname2"
  - "hostname3"
```

Comment: Thank you, looks very straightforward. Do you also know how do I name the file something like 'example.yaml' ?

Comment: `new File('config.yaml') << config.toString()`